# A name for the subsection about the paper structure

Tags: publications, writing

If one wants to have a separate name for the subsection which goes like, 'Section 2 is dedicated to... In Section 3, we discuss... Finally, in Section 4...', then what is the best option? "Outline of the paper"? "Paper structure"? Anything else?

Comment: isn't this part of the Introduction?

Comment: @JonCuster it is. But what if the introduction has its own subsections? This is the case for this question.

Comment: Have you read papers that use this format and name this section? If so, what did they name it? If not, why do you think your paper is different from all the others and should have this section?

Comment: @BryanKrause with due respect, I won't answer your questions. Not only such a subsection is logically possible, I have read such papers but not in English.

Comment: They're [rhetorical questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) so they aren't meant to be answered, at least not for my benefit. My point is to suggest that it's most important to follow conventions in your field; I would not recommend writing a paper in English in a field where you haven't read papers in English, and I wouldn't recommend using a structure that isn't common unless there's a special reason to do so.

Comment: Since this is not a standard (sub)section in the english language journals I'm familiar with, you can probably call it whatever you like. I don't think there is a "best" option, other than to follow whatever the existing conventions are for structure.

Comment: Overview, outline, battleplan, etc. Most papers in my field have it as a paragraph of the introduction, possibly with a sentence such as "This work is divided into n sections." or a bolded "Sections overview" at the beginning of the paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend looking at the formatting guidelines (or simply other papers) of the journal you are aiming to submit to.

If this is not a question relating to this kind of paper, then it probably doesn't matter so much, and I'd say "outline" would be appropriate.